# How to add a way for users to acknowledge the Automated email

Tags: entity-framework, email, model-view-controller, receipt

First time poster, so forgive me for my poor question if this has ben asked before.

I have a C# entity frame work web application that users fill out a form, and after they submit this form, the application sends an email to a group of contractors that have a set amount of time to review and respond to it.

I have all of that working flawlessly. My problem is that I need to find someway for the contractors to acknowledge that they received the email, and save the time in my application.

While I am relatively new to web development, MVC, and entity framework, I have googled and searched but I can't seem to find anything for it. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am thinking I am going to try a web service, and see how that works.